# how to check when did cassandra got shut down or started/re-started from logs?

Tags: cassandra

nodetool status -- shows some nodes as down and also application is not able to reach the cassandra nodes. When I connect to cassandra nodes and check the logs there are some errors in the logs (system.log and debug.log).

Didn't understand how to check if when did Cassandra got started / re-started and got shutdown. Is there any way to check this from logs ? if so which log and how ?

Answer (score 0):

In the logs folder of your Cassandra installation you should find **system.log file**. **The default location for the log files is /var/log/cassandra**.

When Cassandra starts the output looks like this:

```
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:27,162 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/home/20171127/.ccm/3113/node1/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:27,696 Config.java:495 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator;INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:27,698 DatabaseDescriptor.java:367 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:27,699 DatabaseDescriptor.java:425 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 123MB
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:27,700 DatabaseDescriptor.java:429 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 123MB
WARN  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:27,974 DatabaseDescriptor.java:550 - Only 30.922GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,025 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,026 DatabaseDescriptor.java:729 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,265 JMXServerUtils.java:246 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7100/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,282 CassandraDaemon.java:473 - Hostname: 2VVg5
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,284 CassandraDaemon.java:480 - JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_181
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,285 CassandraDaemon.java:481 - Heap size: 495.000MiB/495.000MiB
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,287 CassandraDaemon.java:486 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 4178816(4080K) committed = 4194304(4096K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,289 CassandraDaemon.java:486 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 18530200(18095K) committed = 19005440(18560K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,289 CassandraDaemon.java:486 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2092504(2043K) committed = 2228224(2176K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,290 CassandraDaemon.java:486 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 41943040(40960K) used = 41943040(40960K) committed = 41943040(40960K) max = 41943040(40960K)
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,291 CassandraDaemon.java:486 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 5242880(5120K) used = 5242880(5120K) committed = 5242880(5120K) max = 5242880(5120K)
INFO  [main] 2018-08-18 19:10:28,293 CassandraDaemon.java:486 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 471859200(460800K) used = 669336(653K) committed = 471859200(460800K) max = 471859200(460800K)
```

When Cassandra shuts down properly, the log entries look like this:

```
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2018-08-18 19:28:23,661 Gossiper.java:1559 - Announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2018-08-18 19:28:23,662 StorageService.java:2289 - Node /127.0.0.1 state jump to shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2018-08-18 19:28:25,664 MessagingService.java:992 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-/127.0.0.1] 2018-08-18 19:28:25,665 MessagingService.java:1346 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2018-08-18 19:28:25,729 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
```

Depending on how Cassandra stopped is possible to not have any log entries where you could see that Cassandra stopped.

Other interesting files that you could look into are **debug.log** and **gc.log**.